YoloV9 не обнаруживает объект
Необходимо было проверить, можно ли использовать нейросеть типа YoloV9 для обнаружения горящего светодиода. Собрал небольшой датасет (300 картинок), повращал их на 90 градусов в одну/другую сторону, обучил YoloV9 (пробовал 50, 70, 130 эпох). После 130 эпох, YoloV9
с параметрами для инференса conf_thres": "0.25", "iou_thres":"0.2",
не обнаруживает горящий светодиод, но при этом имеется много ложных обнаружений с вероятностью больше, чем на горящем светодиоде. Причем не детектирует светодиод даже на тех картинках, которые были в тренировочным датасете. Что может быть причиной? 

Мне кажется, это очень мало картинок для обучения. Я бы ещё сдвиги сделал, отражения, сдвиги по яркости-контрастности, по цветам... Хотя может и не в этом дело, конечно.

да, конечно, картинок мало, но вместе с тем, есть же много ложных детектирований - они то откуда берутся, казалось бы  - недостаточно обученная YoloV9 не будет обнаруживать на картинке ничего
или я ошибаюсь?

Ну, у меня впечатление, что она у вас чему-то не тому учится. Я, честно говоря, в данной теме не очень разбираюсь, как обучение детектированию объектов делается не очень понимаю. Отмечаются там как-то объекты, или модель сама их находит?
